# Emergency mode screen and fsck doesn't work

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mode

I'm stuck at the "You are in emergency mode screen" (Ubuntu 20) while trying to log in into my machine.

[image: Picture of the emergency mode screen]

I booted from a liveUSB and run the command fsck but doesn't seem to work. First I listed my drives

[image: Picture of the drive list returned]

And then run fsck. I don't know if it is supposed to perform like this, but hardly anything showed up in the console

[image]

Also, I don't understand why sda1 shows as a boot partition in the drive list, since it is just a storage partition. The computer actually boots from sdb.

Just for context: I ran into this problem when I hard reseted my machine as it freezed during boot up.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After an hour or so of trying, I've found out that on the emergency mode screen you can input your root password and then type "mount -a" and that fixes the problem.

Sorry to bother you, I'm just too inexperienced and Ubuntu has a really steep learning curve.

I'd like to leave this thread undeleted as it may help someone else.

Thank you again for your time and sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: This may be a workaround, but this isn't the proper solution. Did you `fsck` sdb5/7/8? Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `sudo blkid`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.